# Orden Grafico Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Con los datos de siguiente imagen (se muestra sólo una parte) he de crear un gráfico de barras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso no me ha supuesto mayor problema con el siguiente código:

```
labels = weather['Month']
data = weather['Temp[C]']

plt.bar(labels,data)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea principal era que para cada mes, cada barra tuviera un color diferente. Eso lo he conseguido con el siguiente código:

```
grupos = weather.groupby('Month')

plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))

for name, group in grupos:
    plt.bar(group['Month'], group['Temp[C]'])
    plt.ylabel('Temperatura', fontsize = 21)
    
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no me lo muestra en el mismo orden (de Enero a Diciembre).

¿Alguien sabe como podría ser posible conseguirlo?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola jvallejo! Es complicado ayudarte con tan poca información, por favor considera leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `grupos = weather.groupby('Month', sort=False)` para guardar el orden original. Sino,  crea un orden alfabético.